# How to use 'Markdown' in parse_mode of telegram bot?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

```
bot.on(/^\/s (.+)$/, async function(msg, props) {
      let id = msg.chat.id;
      let message = await MyBot.getBySearchQuery(props.match[1]);
      let parse_mode = 'Markdown';
      return bot.sendMessage(id, message, { parse_mode });
    });
```

By `/s <param>` I want to get some [hyperlink](http://someurl) in telegram. But instead of that I'm getting `[hyperlink](http://some_url)`.

What is going wrong here? The `message` here is always a string like `[title](url)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This reason yours isn't working is because you called it `parse_mode` instead of `parseMode` ([See doc](https://github.com/mullwar/telebot#sendmessagechat_id-text-parsemode-replytomessage-replymarkup-notification-webpreview))

Try this, it should work.

```
const TeleBot = require('telebot');

const bot = new TeleBot('35353453:sfsdfsdffgrtyrty454646thfhfgfgh')

bot.on(/^\/s (.+)$/, async function(msg, props) {
  const id = msg.chat.id;
  const url = "https://google.com";
  const message = `Read more about [Google](${url}) now!!!!`;

  return bot.sendMessage(id, message, { parseMode: 'Markdown' });
});

bot.start();
```

Okay, I tested it and it works well. I sent `/s ert` and here was the response:

[image]

So now let me click `Google` and you'll see the popup:
[image]

THERE YOU GO. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [node-telegram-bot-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-telegram-bot-api) npm module?

I think you want to be using `bot.onText` method not `.on`. I've just tried with both, and when using .on the callback function never runs.

```js
bot.onText(/^\/s (.+)$/, async function(msg, props) {
  let id = msg.chat.id;
  let message = await MyBot.getBySearchQuery(props.match[1]);
  let parse_mode = 'Markdown';
  return bot.sendMessage(id, message, { parse_mode });
});
```

Have you tried adding some kind of logging to this method to see if it ever actually runs, and that your `getBySearchQuery(..)` is returning the expected message?

Comment: Yes, `getBySearchQuery(..)` is returning the expected message

Comment: @EvgenyBagrov then have you tried using `parseMode` as the parameter name instead? https://github.com/mullwar/telebot#sendmessagechat_id-text-parsemode-replytomessage-replymarkup-notification-webpreview